# JBoss served application - using apache proxypass session is not accessible

Tags: java, apache, session, jboss, proxypass

Am encountering a strange (to me) situation with a java application served out of JBoss.

**--Background--**

1)
JBoss is installed in a Linux environment.

For the sake of explanation, the IP address on my environment is: 99.999.999.99

2)
Within the environment, I have JBoss running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080

With several applications which can be reached at: http://127.0.0.1:8080/APPLICATION_NAME

3)
I have apache routing traffic to my IP address as follows:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/

ProxyPass /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/

ProxyPass /app3/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app3/
ProxyPassReverse /app3/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app3/
```

4)
When I access 99.999.999.99 I am able to access app1, which functions as expected (except for the issue below).

When I access 99.999.999.99/app2 I am able to access app2.

**--Issue--**

1)
Inside of app1, I have a jsp page which writes to the session:

_sessionTest1.jsp
session.setAttribute("test", "test");

2)
The problem is that after running this JSP, the session will not contain the data that was set.

3)
If I remove the apache proxies, and instead, expose JBoss root, with also 
the administration links and JMX console, the session will be updated as expected.

When configured in this manner, the way I access the application is:

99.999.999.99/app1

Where 99.999.999.99 will show my JBoss root.

4)
Is it expected that the session for an application would not be accessible if configured as above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was with apache needing to be configured to look for the session information from the cookie, instead of URL which is default.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem with Apache proxying Jetty. The rule was:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8080
```

Which proxied `https://myhost/myapp` to `http://localhost:8080`. This worked in general, but the session in myapp was not preserved between requests. Adding the following rule fixed it:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your first proxy statement should in fact be your last. Apache will stop at the first rule that matches the URL so all of your requests through your web server are catching rule 1 with the generic /.

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/

ProxyPass /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app2/

ProxyPass /app3/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app3/
ProxyPassReverse /app3/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/app3/

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1/
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct with this. I actually had it last, but put it first in the explanation to try and keep it more clear.